# How to define a custom tooltip in Apex chart in React?

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

I am defining four lines chart with Apex Chart.
My data series:

```
series: [
            {
              name: "first",
              data: [28, 29, 33, 36, 32, 32, 33]
            },
            {
              name: "second",
              data: [12, 11, 14, 18, 17, 13, 13]
            },
            {
                name: "third",
                data: [48, 29, 33, 16, 32, 62, 3]
              },
              {
                name: "forth",
                data: [22, 11, 54, 18, 27, 53, 13]
              }
        ],
```

I want my tooltip output to be like:

```
first-label : {series.dataOfFirstLabel}

second-label : {series.dataOfSecondLabel}

third-label : {series.dataOfThirdLabel}

forth-label : {series.dataOfForthLabel}
```

How can I define my custom tooltip?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you share what you've tried already? Or if there's anything specific that's causing a problem with the custom tooltip? There's some information about custom tooltips in the [documentation](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/tooltip/).

Answer (score 2):

Instead string literal you can use renderToString from react-dom/server.

```
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
```

So the custom function would look like this:

```
// Some series that you use in the chart
const seriesData = [
{
    name: 'South',
    data: [
        [1486771200000, 40],
        [1486857600000, 18],
        [1486944000000, 43],
    ],
},
{
    name: 'North',
    data: [
        [1486771200000, 16],
        [1486857600000, 15],
        [1486944000000, 10],
    ],
}]

... 

// Tooltip option for apexChart
tooltip: {
    custom: ({ series, seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w }) => {
        
        const xValue = seriesData[seriesIndex].data[dataPointIndex][0]
        const xDate = new Date(xValue).toLocaleDateString('cs-CZ')

        return renderToString(
            <div>
                <p>
                    {xDate}
                </p>
                {/* Map through series to get labels and values */}
                {seriesData.map((s, i) => (
                    <div key={s.name} className="tooltipItem">
                        <div style={{ 
                            minWidth: "12px", 
                            backgroundColor: w.globals.colors[i]
                        }}
                        />
                        
                        <p >
                            MyLabel:{' '}
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            {series[i][dataPointIndex]}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        )
    },
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
tooltip: {
  custom: function (series: any) { 
 return `<div>
                                ${series.map((el: any) => {
                                            return `<div class="d-flex  flex-    column"> 
                                                <p>${el.name}-label:${el.data.map((element: any)=>element).join("")}</p> </div>`; })  
                             </div>`},}
```

https://codepen.io/apexcharts/pen/NBdyvV

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In chart options

```
enter code here
tooltip: {
  enabled: true,
  enabledOnSeries: true,
  shared: true,
  followCursor: true,
  intersect: false,
  inverseOrder: false,
  custom: undefined,
  fillSeriesColor: true,
  theme: false,
  style: {
    fontSize: "12px",
    fontFamily: undefined,
  },
  onDatasetHover: {
    highlightDataSeries: false,
  },
  x: {
    show: true,
    format: "dd MMM",
    formatter: undefined,
  },
  y: {
    show: false,
    formatter: undefined,
    title: {
      formatter: (seriesName) => seriesName,
    },
  },
  z: {
    formatter: undefined,
    title: "Size: ",
  },
  marker: {
    show: false,
  },
  items: {
    display: "flex",
  },
  fixed: {
    enabled: false,
    position: "topRight",
    offsetX: 0,
    offsetY: 0,
  },
},
//sh
```

you can add these properties
refer - https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/tooltip/